# RNN-based Predictions of Sine Waves with Frequency Different From Training Data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, rnn

I am wondering if I can generate a sine wave with a frequency different from training data using RNN. For example,

Using two training data of two time series, say 0[sec] ~ 10[sec] each:
sin(t) and sin(2t)

If we feed these two data to RNN, can we possibly predict a sine wave of sin(1.5t) with some amount of initial data?

I would be very appreciated if you could tell me the possibility of this, and perhaps some examples of implementation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think that would be challenging. Why not use a Fourier Series instead? It might be a good idea to take a step back, and not necessarily dive into an ML algorithm immediately.